# Use external terminal

Tags: netbeans, terminal

How can I have Netbeans run my Java project inside a system terminal rather than its built-in terminal?

I looked around and apparently I am supposed to do `Project Properties->Run->Console Type` but this has regrettably been removed from the project configuration panel at some point in history.

Every other thread I can dig up on the internet regarding this issue has - predictably - no replies.

I know I can run the jar file from the command-line but an integrated solution would be helpful.

I am using Netbeans 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can be done for an Ant project but it can be done for a Maven project.

- Create a Maven Project. File -> New Project. Select Category "Maven" and Project Type "Java Application". Click Next and then Finish to accept project defaults.
- Add a Main class with a public static void main(String args[]) method. Expand Source Packages in the Projects window. Select any package. Right-click -> New -> "Java Class".

Add something to wait for output before exiting or your terminal will exit without your having time to view the output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        br.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- Select the project in the projects window. Right-click for pop-up. Choose Properties. Select category "Run". Click the Browse button next to Main class and select the Main class.
- Run the project one time  normally with the green triangle on the toolbar, menu Run-> Run Project or F6.
- Expland the "Project Files" node in the projects window. Double-click "nbactions.xml".
- Change the Properties for the "run" action. Change executable to your terminal and add the appropriate flags and java to the arguments.

eg. From :

```
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-classpath %classpath wshackle.mavenproject2.Main</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        </properties>
```

to :

```
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-x java -classpath %classpath wshackle.mavenproject2.Main</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>gnome-terminal</exec.executable>
        </properties>
```

or for Windows:

```
        <properties>
            <exec.args>/c java -classpath %classpath wshackle.mavenproject2.Main</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>cmd</exec.executable>
        </properties>
```

- Save and close this file.
- Run the project. It should now open up in an external terminal.

Note: I provided the same answer here:
[display netbeans java output terminal on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902866/display-netbeans-java-output-terminal-on-the-command-line/31905425#31905425)