# how can i get my Netbeans output on a terminal window?

Tags: netbeans, terminal, operating-system, settings

Is there anyway for me to run my code in netbeans and get the output in a terminal window rather than the output window of netbeans? (I'm using netbeans 8.0.1 on ubuntu 12.04)
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a C++ project:

Right click on the project -> select properties -> select Run -> change console type from internal terminal to external terminal.

For Java applications, I surprisingly couldn't find any option: [Use external terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096497/use-external-terminal). The best I have found now is to make the output window float (right click on the output window and select float group).

Comment: its java actually. So it's impossible?

Comment: I think it is indeed not possible in Netbeans for Java applications. I thought it was also possible till now, but then I realised I've been only using it for C++ applications. Of course, you could run it like for instance java -jar myapp.jar on your own console. But I can understand that it can be annoying during development.

Comment: The best thing I could find was to right click the output window and select 'float group'.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ projects (in newer versions of NetBeans; not sure about Java):
Left click on File -> Project Properties -> Run -> Console Type -> External Terminal

Answer (score 0):

I got the terminal in Netbeans for Java,
You just need to open your project then :
select: Tools >> open in Terminal.
That's it!.